# moment.localeData().longDateFormat("L") is not returning the right format for date based on locale

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the date format for my region based on locale so as to pass it as format to my Material ui datepicker. But then thought I changes my locale to UK, and locale is now en-GB, the  moment.localeData().longDateFormat("L") still returns MM/DD/YYYY while i expected it to be DD/MM/YYYY

The code is here
https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-benz-yzvhx

As per this https://momentjs.com/, 
moment().format('L') should be 20/03/2020

Answer (score -1):

for this, you will need `moment-timezone` an npm module by MomentJs
and refer to the [Docs Here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

Comment: I did pass the right format -- moment().format('L')

Comment: that's the time zone you need So add npm package `moment-timezone` and then use it to format your date you need to set the timezone and the format the data